# traceback error keeping me from scatter 5.0

Tags: python, installation

I have been sent here by the scatter guys. Attached is the error message that comes up when i try to install scatter 5. it seems that my machine is blocking some folders for install. Not sure how to trouble shoot this error.i tried to do a fresh reinstall of blender and it still happens. any ideas?  Thanks. [image]

Comment: At first glance, this looks to me neither a bug in Blender, nor a bug in Scatter5. But still the developers of Scatter5 should be able to help you in this case, as it would be possible here. What about your user rights on this system in general? Admin? Restricted user?

Comment: i am an admin. The scatter guys are trying. they are working with me. firstly going into the security permission and clicking on modify and write abilites. seemed like it should be the solution but is still an issue. I noticed that this happend after i installed 2 scattering addons. True terrian and this one. befor this i had no issues.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26091530/permissionerror-winerror-5-access-is-denied-python-using-moviepy-to-write-gif

Answer (score 0):

Just solved that problem: when you click on "Open Biomes", the image editor (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>) must NOT be opened.

If you are seeing your render, close that first.